# Regex for strings starting with letters/_ and (possibly) following letters/digits/_

Tags: .net, regex, f#

Why isn't this regex working for the string "Array a"?

```
let mutable line = "Array a"
let regexIdentifier = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")   
line <- regexIdentifier.Replace(line, "\r\n$&\r\n")   //KEYWORDS separation
Console.WriteLine(line)
```

(I want the program to separate both "Array" and "a" to different lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern separate the "Array a" in two distinct matches

```
string rPattern = @"\b[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]+\b";
```

works also for a string like

```
"Exam_ple1 a9"
```

- The `\b` limits the pattern at the word boundaries. (this gives back
  two Matches for the input text also if you have more than one space between)
- The first character should be from the ranges A-Za-z or an underscore (not numbers).
- The following characters should be from the ranges A-Za-z0-9 or an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace in `"Array a"` isnt matched.

Better use a regexp like `"^[\w_]+ [\w_]+$"`

Answer (score 0):

^ mean top of line
$ mean end of line
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$ mean form top to end

use @"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"